# Speeding the initialization of the X.org server, greeter, and session

Tags: ubuntu, x11, xorg, display

### Background

I am currently experiencing a long "startup" time on my machine (and was well before gorilla):

```
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.               sterlingbutters@butters-ubuntu 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           ------------------------------ 
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu Groovy Gorilla (development branch) x86_64 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Kernel: 5.8.0-16-generic 
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Uptime: 45 mins 
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Packages: 3776 (dpkg), 9 (snap) 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Shell: bash 5.0.17 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Resolution: 3840x2160 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   DE: GNOME 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM: Mutter 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM Theme: Adwaita 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Theme: Yaru [GTK2/3] 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Icons: Yaru [GTK2/3] 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/    Terminal: gnome-terminal 
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+     CPU: Intel i9-7940X (28) @ 4.400GHz 
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/      GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 Ti 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Memory: 6434MiB / 31817MiB 
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`                                   
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.
```

Looking at the `journalctl`, it appears that it takes approximately 44 seconds (from the first entry) to initialize the X server. I deduced this using `lightdm`'s system hooks i.e.:

#### `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-system-hooks.conf`

```
[SeatDefaults]
display-setup-script=echo "This text is produced after the X server starts but before the user session / greeter is run. Change the display-setup-script in /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-system-hooks.conf to configure anything special here. It is run as root. If this command returns an error code the X server is stopped."
display-stopped-script=echo "This text is produced after the X server exits. Change the display-stopped-script in /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-system-hooks.conf to configure anything special here. It is run as root."
greeter-setup-script=echo "This text is produced before a greeter starts. Change the greeter-setup-script in /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-system-hooks.conf to configure anything special here. It is run as root. If this command returns an error code the greeter fails to start (which will cause LightDM to stop)."
session-setup-script=echo "This text is produced before a user session starts. Change the session-setup-script in /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-system-hooks.conf to configure anything special here. If this command returns an error the session will not start (user is returned to a greeter)."
session-cleanup-script=echo "This text is produced after a greeter or user session stops. Change the session-cleanup-script in /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-system-hooks.conf to configure anything special here. It is run as root." 
#session-wrapper= is a the command to run for a session. This command is run as the user and needs to exec the command passed in the arguments to complete running the session. Use this if you need to do special setup for a user session. Note the default is 'lightdm-session' so you should chain to this if you need to override this setting.
#greeter-wrapper= is a the command to run a greeter. It is the equivalent of session-wrapper for greeters.
```

This seems like a very long time to initiate the X server especially considering my machine's specifications.

## What are some reasons for a X server's inititation to take so long?

Additionally, it takes very little time (<1s) to start the greeter (unity) once the X server is initialized. What is odd to me about this is even though `systemctl get-default` equates to `graphical.target`, I see the console momentarily (~2s) before the greeter is diplayed (not the biggest deal - just weird).

Entering my credentials into the greeter almost immediately yields ~23s between the greeter initialization and user session initilization. This where timelines start to become discrepant: even though the greeter accepts the credentials and appears to start the user session, I generally wait ~1min between the credentials and a usable desktop (that is, I can see the wallpaper and use the mouse but no icons, menu, windows, etc are visible).

I see that `lightdm` initializes the Greeter via:

#### `/usr/share/xgreeters/unity-greeter.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Unity Greeter
Comment=Unity Greeter
Exec=unity-greeter
Type=Application
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=unity-greeter
```

and the DE via

#### `/usr/share/xsessions/ubuntu.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Ubuntu
Comment=This session logs you into Ubuntu
Exec=env GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu /usr/bin/gnome-session --systemd --session=ubuntu
TryExec=/usr/bin/gnome-shell
Type=Application
DesktopNames=ubuntu:GNOME
X-GDM-SessionRegisters=true
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-session-3.0
```

using the following files:

#### `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf`

```
[Seat:*]
user-session=ubuntu
```

#### `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf`

```
[Seat:*]
greeter-session=unity-greeter
```

(though I am not sure what `50-greeter-wrapper.conf`: `[Seat:*]\n greeter-wrapper=/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-greeter-session` is in the same directory)

Comment: Are you using an SSD or a spinning disk?  If the latter, what is its speed in RPM?

Comment: @bk2204 Seagate FireCuda Gaming SSHD 2TB 7200 RPM 64MB Cache SATA 6.0Gb/s 3.5" Internal Hard Drive ST2000DX002 - I will see if I can figure out its *actual* speed somehow

Comment: The speed is 7200 RPM.  The problem is likely because of your disk; you're loading a lot of data off disk when you start a session and that isn't an especially fast disk these days.

Comment: @bk2204 what sort of improvement should I be looking for with an SSD? If it takes ~2min from start button to desktop right now? Half the time?

Comment: I use Debian unstable with MATE on an SSD and it's seconds for me.  I don't know if that's the cause here; you'd have to do some actual measurement to see how long it takes each thing to start.  It may be you have some dependent service that is slow for some other reason and is causing your problems.

Comment: Well I don't think the disk is 100% to blame and my `systems-analyze` looks good. I'm sure it would be faster with an SSD but I don't think that's the root of the problem